# Returning a variable name in a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

As I'm debugging, I'm consistently writing this bit of code:

```js
a = 2;
// do some operation on variable a
console.log("The a variable is now " + a);
```

I wondered if I might create a function that shortens that process, like this,

```js
function varlog(x) {
  var vartext = // this is what I don't know
  return "The " + vartext + " variable is now " + x;
}

var a = 2;
console.log(varlog(a));
```

Two questions,

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem that I'm not seeing?
2. If not, what should the vartext be to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this isn't possible, because what's being passed to the varlog function isn't "a," but "2." Put a different way, varlog doesn't have any idea what "a" is.

Comment: This isn’t possible. Try something like `a = 2; b = 4; console.log({ a, b });` instead. This will log `Object { a: 2, b: 4 }`.

Comment: See [Variable name as a string in Javascript](/q/4602141/4642212).

Comment: Use a debugger that shows you all variables with their values. Logging something like `console.log("a = ", a)` should be *very* short-term and not something to rely upon extensively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "[Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)" as below

```
function easyDebug(variable){

    let name = Reflect.ownKeys(variable)[0];
    let vals = JSON.stringify(variable[name]);
    console.log("The ( "+ name +" ) variable is now = ( " + vals +" )");
}

let a=5;
easyDebug({a});
//Will output
//The ( a ) variable is now = ( 5 )

let arr=[5,6,7];
easyDebug({arr});
//Will output
//The ( arr ) variable is now = ( [5,6,7] )

let obj={"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"};
easyDebug({obj});
//Will output
//The ( obj ) variable is now = ( {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"} )

let obj2={obj};
easyDebug({obj2});
//Will output
//The ( obj2 ) variable is now = ( {"obj":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}} )

let arrObj = [obj];
easyDebug({arrObj});
//Will output
//The ( arrObj ) variable is now = ( [{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}] )
```

Comment: Well, `Reflect` really isn’t necessary here; this is also not usually what `Reflect` is used for (it’s mostly used as the default action in [Proxies](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)). This is no different from the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

By handing over a variable, the name is not known. the only part, where a variable is known, is to use [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), where the variable name is now the property.

```js
function varlog(x) {
    const [k, v] = Object.entries(x)[0];
    return `The ${k} variable is now ${v}`;
}

const a = 2;

console.log(varlog({ a })); // call with short hand property
```